# Getting user email from a List Item column using Javascript

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I am creating a Hosted app using NAPA on Sharepoint 2013 (Office365). I need to retrive a user from a list column and get the user's email.

SP.List.getItems with a query returns a listEnumerator correctly. However, the user field is of type SPFieldUserValue. This does not appear to have a property called User from which I can retrieve the email (the C# version of SPFieldUserValue has a User property). Any idea on how I can get the user's email in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you Author column (user) with email from a list 'Test':

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Test')/Items?$select=Author/EMail&$expand=Author/EMail
```

You can replace 'Author' with any other Person/Group column.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use [SP.Web.ensureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408786.aspx) method to retrieve user by it's logon name, after this you can use [SP.User.email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245596.aspx) property.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady() {
    //retrieve logonName

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var user = web.ensureUser(logonName);

    clientContext.load(user);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('The email address of the current user is ' + user.get_email());
    alert('The account name is ' + user.get_loginName());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get the email of a user from a list column, not the current user. Unfortunately, SPFieldUserValue only returns the Display Name and not the logon name. So this won't work.

Comment: you also can try to use [User Information List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553401.aspx). See [this example](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/10/15/retrieve-all-user-in-sharepoint-2010-site-using-javascript-client-object-model/). It should store user's email.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done for any person field not just current user.
Get lookupvalue from person field(contact in this case) and the get the user field.

```
var userName = currentRd.get_item("Contact").get_lookupValue();

user = web.ensureUser(userName);
```

Everything else should work the same way as Alexander said.

Answer (score 0):

From the list API you can use select statement as below 
siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items&$select=Author/EMail 
and from the result iterate like below

var itemcount = apiResultValue.length;
var itemsresult = JSON.stringify(apiResultValue); 
itemsresult = JSON.parse(itemsresult);
if (itemcount > 0) {
alert(**itemsresult[0].Author.Email**); 
//above line will get the email of user from list createdby user column
}

Hope it will help someone :)